# Does the windows 8 internet explorer 10 still have quirksmode?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, quirks-mode

I'm wondering if IE10 on Windows 8 still has Quirksmode in it. Because we have a webapplication that (still :|) works with quirksmode and I want to know if it is still working on Windows 8.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

IE10 has two quirk modes. The new one is called "Quirks mode" and behaves exactly the same as quirks mode in Firefox and Webkit - you can turn it on by removing `<!doctype>`. All HTML5 and other new features work in this mode. Only some minor spec violations are present (not requiring units in CSS dimensions and so on).

The legacy quirks mode is called "IE5 Quirks mode" and behaves as quirks mode in IE9. You can turn it on with `X-UA-Compatible: IE=5` HTTP header or `<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=5">` tag. In this mode, IE renders the page as old IE5.

For better notion, look at how IE renders Acid2 test in new quirks mode:
[image: new quirks mode]
and IE5 quirks mode:
[image: IE5 quirks mode]

If your application works also in Chrome and Firefox, you'll probably want to use Quirks mode; if only IE's quirks mode is supported, turn on IE5 quirks mode.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: The 1st rendering... [Homestar Runner](http://www.hrwiki.org/w/images/thumb/a/a4/NewestHomestar.png/180px-NewestHomestar.png)?

Comment: description of x-ua-compatible headers -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Answer (score 2):

**Quirks** mode is listed in IE10 developer tools ([**Document Mode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#bdmodes)) on Windows 8 - so yes [it appears it is supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx).