# What exactly is "IE5 quirks" in IE 10 Developer Tools?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-10, web-standards, quirks-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the windows 8 internet explorer 10 still have quirksmode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865188/does-the-windows-8-internet-explorer-10-still-have-quirksmode)

I'm working on a website which we're trying to get to work in IE10. In this site we have an iframe which is breaking when we're using IE5 quirksmode which we really need for the `main` site to work, for some reason we can't just use the Quirks document mode in IE10, because then the main site wont work.

So what the heck is `IE5 quirks` and is it the same as `quirks` in IE9|8?

inb4 OP is `non-standars compliant`: this is a legacy product and we're working hard on a new edition of it.

Comment: I don't really want to delete this question because I think that the title is more describing than the title of the question with the actual answer so I'll leave it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Does the windows 8 internet explorer 10 still have quirksmode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865188/does-the-windows-8-internet-explorer-10-still-have-quirksmode)

> IE10 has two quirk modes. The new one is called "Quirks mode" and behaves exactly the same as quirks mode in Firefox and Webkit - you can turn it on by removing `<!doctype>`. All HTML5 and other new features work in this mode. Only some minor spec violations are present (not requiring units in CSS dimensions and so on).
>
> The legacy quirks mode is called "IE5 Quirks mode" and behaves as quirks mode in IE9. You can turn it on with X-UA-Compatible: IE=5 HTTP header or  tag. In this mode, IE renders the page as old IE5.

If this helped you go and update `duri's` answer and not this one!