# Force HTML page in IE10 to use IE Quirks mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Indulge me, I'm fighting with IE.

We have a set of pages that work nicely in IE8 (intranet). The company decided upgrading directly to IE10.

What is the html code to force a page to use I5 Quirks Mode (this is the mode it works). I've tried with :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE5"  />
```

But IE10 put's the page in quirks mode (not IE5). You open the debugger (F12) and there you can change the document mode and the browser mode. The important is to set the document mode in IE5 quirks

Some help is welcomed

Comment: Well, how about chosing `IE=IE8` then?

Comment: Your company did the right thing by upgrading and not holding everyone back. You should either add the IE8 Compatible META tag or add it as a response header in IIS. Kudos to your company for not holding everyone back! You work in a good place, at least that is a great sign. Now get to work updating your application for the future! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved somewhere else

[Does the windows 8 internet explorer 10 still have quirksmode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865188/does-the-windows-8-internet-explorer-10-still-have-quirksmode)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx

```
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=5">
```

So, your value is false, it's `IE=5` and not `IE=IE5`

Answer (score -4):

IE10 does not have an IE5 mode. They updated Quirks Mode to be more like IE9 (I think, not sure on that) so it's more in line with Chrome/Firefox/etc.. The best it can do is IE7.

Comment: You mean the worst, not the best :)

Comment: Umm... yes it does, I was just debugging some code that was defaulting to IE5 quirks mode in IE10.

Comment: If the site in IE10 is in Compatibility view, then the page is rendered in IE5 Quirks mode.